# Python 3.7 JSON - AttributeError 'dict has no attribute "read"'

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, attributeerror

I was doing simple exercises with JSON and, suddenly, I began to find errors that prevent dictionaries from being converted to JSON and recorded in files:

```
import json

i = {
    "element" : "some element",
    "items" : [
        1, "true", "thing"
    ],
    "nested": {
        "dfadf": "1",
        "adfgf": "2"
    }
}

file = json.load(i)
```

Returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "context-manager.py", line 15, in 
    file = json.load(i)
  File (...)"\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'read'
PS (...)\json>
```

I tried to paste basic functional code but got the same error, or 'write' error when try to dump to file. Is my Python's installation broken, maybe? (I use a company's notebook, but everything was fine till yesterday)
Setup: Windows 10, Python 3.7.4 (running with command 'py' to not launch Python 2.7)

Thanks very much for your opinion!

Comment: `i` is not JSON, it's a dictionary.

Comment: Use `json.dumps()` to dump to a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to open the file and use `json.dump` to write the json to that file

```
with open("filename.json", 'w+') as file:
  json.dump(file, i)
```

The argument `w+` will create the file if it doesn't exists

If you only want to convert it to a string without writing to file, use `json.dumps`

```
json_content = json.dumps(i)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. The problem was in the 'w+'  parameter of open(). I keep the 'r' to preserve and use the content till final writing, but forgot it and   start to randomize code.